# How to insert a double quote in a string?

Tags: swift, text

I want insert " in my variable string:

```
let myText : String = "\(")"
print("the result "+myText)
```

**The result I want**

> the result "

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Xcode 6.x and Xcode 7.0 you have to escape the `"` character with a `\` to be able to insert it in a string:

```
let myText = "\""
print("the result " + myText)
```

Result:

> the result "

Comment: it does not give expected result. instead it gives as  the result \"

Comment: when you print it does not print as expected.

Comment: same thing is happening to me @boom

Comment: @Adam We're talking about what is *printed* in the output console. If you're using a Playground, we're not talking about what the playground displays in its side panel, which indeed shows the slash. boom made the same mistake of interpreting a literal representation of the string (panel in playground or else) instead of focusing on the printed result - which is the topic of this question and answer.

Comment: You can see it in [this screenshot](https://monosnap.com/file/7O9uMcsP0uzQ3jDBOQStdAFqjWFlBe). It *prints* what I show in my answer. This is the real string. Not what you see in the side panel.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code for **Swift 5, Xcode 10.2**

```
let myText = #"the result ""#
print(myText)
```

Output:

> the result "

Comment: Thank you!!  I was trying but it was not working "\"".